# DRF - Add User to a model with ManyToManyField

Tags: django-rest-framework

I am trying to implement a feature to my backend and allow the owner of private "Group" to add other users by their usernames instead of ID's and allow them to add their images to FileField only once after they were added to the model. The code I have so far:

models.py

```
class Group(models.Model):
    group_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    group_text = models.TextField(max_length=360, blank=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='owner_user', on_delete=models.SET(get_deleted_user), default=1)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    shared_to = models.ManyToManyField(UserProfile, blank=True, related_name='shared_to_user', null=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.group_name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Group, self).save(*args, **kwargs)



class GroupImage(models.Model):
    group_file = models.FileField(blank=True, null=True,
                                    upload_to='media/covers/%Y/%m/%D/')

    gallery_group = models.ForeignKey(Group, related_name='images', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

serializers.py

```
class GroupImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.GroupImage
        fields = ('group_file', )


class SharedToSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Group
        fields = ('shared_to', )


class GroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    
    images = GroupImageSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    person = SharedToSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)


    class Meta:
        model = models.Group
        fields = ('id', 'group_name', 'group_text', 'person', 'images')
        
    def create(self, validated_data):
        images_data = self.context.get('view').request.FILES
        owner_id = self.context['request'].user.id
        gallery_group = models.Group.objects.create(group_name=validated_data.get('group_name', 'no- 
             group_name'), group_text=validated_data.get('group_text'), owner_id=1)
        for image_data in images_data.values():
            models.GroupImage.objects.create(gallery_group=gallery_group, 
                 group_file=image_data)
            return gallery_group
```

views.py

```
class GroupCreateAPIView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = models.Group.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.GroupSerializer
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
```

Comment: So instead of using model serializer and createapiview that give you out of the box api, why don't you try to create your own serializer and write your view set, do the mapping of url to the specific viewset method. Read the docs regarding viewsets and serializer, try to come up with some logic. Then try it and show us what you have. Will be a good learning experience for you

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, but my question seems to be more specific

Comment: @oniqqq can you provide some sample data on which you are working? I mean it will be easy to comprehend; how you want your API to behave :)

Comment: `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` and `UserProfile` points to same model?

Comment: I didn't fully understand your question. First of all, what is the problem? You stated what you want and gave us some code but didn't really say what the problem is. Please be more specific

Comment: I don't fully understand what's the better way  to modify my serializer in order to add a list of users by their usernames to ManyToManyField.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if your only requirement is how to add users by their username and not their id. You should use SlugRelatedField. I also feel your serializer naming convention is quite confusing. Below is the serializer for Group model that can add users to a group.

```
class GroupSerializer(Serializer):
    ... other fields here
    shared_to = models.SlugRelatedField(queryset = UserProfile.objects.all(), many=True, slug_field="username", allow_empty=True)
```

So first checkout [SlugRelatedField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#slugrelatedfield). This basically is used to map to objects using a specific field of that object(username in this case). You will then get all the `UserProfile` instances in the `shared_to` field of the `validated_data`
property of the serializer which you can fetch in create method and add to you group. And then in the file upload api for your group you can check whether this user belongs to the group or not for permission checking.

Comment: if you are satisfied with the answer maybe you could upvote it.